# Scraping my search result on LinkedIn but having trouble locating certain buttons

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver

I'm using python and Selenium to scrape some search results in LinkedIn but I'm having trouble finding the people button on the top left in order to filter my results to have only people. I noticed that the ID of the button is dynamic so I tried different ways to find the buttons, all of which have failed. Here is the HTML code of the button:

```
<div class="peek-carousel js-slideshow">
    <ul class="peek-carousel__slides js-list">
        <li class="mr2">
            <button aria-checked="false" role="radio" aria-label="People" id="ember69" class="artdeco-pill artdeco-pill--slate artdeco-pill--2 artdeco-pill--choice ember-view search-reusables__filter-pill-button" type="button"> People </button>
```

and here are my three attempts (python code):

```
1) people_button = driver.find_element_by_css_selector("#people + button")
2) people_button = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//button[@aria-label='People']")
3) people_button = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//button[@aria-label='People'][@type='button']")
```

I'm having also the same problem for the next button on the bottom right to go to the next page here is the HTML code of the button:

```
 <span class="artdeco-button__text">
 Next
 </span>
```

Answer (score 0):

The first locator doesn't work because there is no element with an ID "people" on the page. The second and third work fine for me. I've tested them in the dev tools in Chrome using `$$()` for CSS selector and `$x()` for XPath. In this case, `$x("//button[@aria-label='People']")` returns a single element. My guess is that you need to add a wait.

I would use a CSS selector in this case because they are faster and better supported, e.g. "button[aria-label='People']". But, since you used XPath this should work

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

new WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable(By.XPath("//button[@aria-label='People']"))).click()
```

Comment: Why do i need to add the wait? do you think that the button is hidden?

Comment: Also i tried your code in python but it returns invalid syntax, can you explain what your code does please?

Comment: Since I tested the locator and it worked, the only reason I could think of that it might not be clicking is because it's not initially available when the page is loaded so I added a wait. It looks like I missed a closing paren. Fixed now.