# Unable to select the LinkedIn 'people' button using Python Selenium

Tags: python, selenium, linkedin-api

I'm trying to make my first automation program with Python and I've been stuck on a step for a few days. As soon as my program does a search on LinkedIn, I'd like to be able to click on People or Companies for example, but I can't do that using XPath.

Here is my code so far:

```
# Import libraries and packages for the project 
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from time import sleep
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
import csv

# Task 1: Login to Linkedin
# Task 1.1: Open Chrome and Access Linkedin login site
options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.add_experimental_option('excludeSwitches', ['enable-logging'])
driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path="C:\Program Files (x86)\chromedriver.exe", options=options)
sleep(2)
driver.maximize_window()
driver.get('https://www.linkedin.com/login')
sleep(2)

# Task 1.2: Key in login credentials
email_field = driver.find_element(By.ID, 'username')
email_field.send_keys('XXXXXXXXX@.com')
sleep(3)

password_field = driver.find_element(By.NAME, 'session_password')
password_field.send_keys('XXXXXXX')
sleep(2)

# Task 1.2: Click the Login button
signin_field = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '//*[@id="organic-div"]/form/div[3]/button')
signin_field.click()
sleep(3)


# Task 2: Search for the profile we want to crawl
# Task 2.1: Locate the search bar element
search_field = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '//*[@id="global-nav-typeahead"]/input')
# Task 2.2: Input the search query to the search bar
search_query = 'Software Engineer'
search_field.send_keys(search_query)
# Task 2.3: Search
search_field.send_keys(Keys.RETURN)
```

Comment: Are you getting any error ? At which line or step you stuck ?

Comment: Hello,

I have no error when running with this code I posted, but I can't find how I will go forward, I want to click on the 'People' or 'Companies' button for example, but I can't find how I can locate them.
There's that topic there [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67188556/scraping-my-search-result-on-linkedin-but-having-trouble-locating-certain-button#comment118776488_67188638), except the People button doesn't have an "aria-label" to locate it)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the below xpath to click on `people`

**xpath**

```
//button[normalize-space()='People']
```

**Example**

```
element = WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//button[normalize-space()='People']")))

element.click();
```

*To click on* `Companies`

**xpath**

```
//button[normalize-space()='Companies']
```

**Example**

```
elementCom = WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//button[normalize-space()='Companies']")))

elementCom .click();
```

***Imports***

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
```

Comment: Thank you, I'm getting an error message, "new" is not defined.
should I do something first? I just paste this line below my code.

Comment: I updated the answer try that one as is.

Comment: Thank you very much, it works.
I have a question please, how did you get "//button[normalize-space()='People']", because when I copy Xpath from the site, I don't have that.
Thanks again.

Comment: Please upvote and accept the answer if it's work for you. Also, you can see this from 
 here [https://devhints.io/xpath]